# Ruby on Rails 4: test nested resources with rspec not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, mongoid

i have some troubles with testing my ruby on rails application. I have a resource Restaurant and a nested resource menu.

Routes file:

```
resources :restaurants do
  resources :menus
```

Menu model:

```
class Menu
include Mongoid::Document

belongs_to :restaurant
accepts_nested_attributes_for :restaurant

validates :name, presence: true
validates :description, presence: true
validates :restaurant, presence: true

field :name, type: String
field :description, type: String
end
```

restaurant model:

```
class Restaurant
include Mongoid::Document

has_one :address, dependent: :destroy
has_many :menus, dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :address, :menus

validates :name, presence: true
validates :description, presence: true
validates :address, presence: true

field :name, type: String
field :description, type: String
field :thumbnail, type: String
field :banner, type: String
end
```

then, i am trying something like this. it is a default test from rspec, but which i am trying to modify because i had a nested resource..

```
describe MenusController do

before :each do
@restaurant = FactoryGirl.create(:random_restaurant)
@menu = FactoryGirl.create(:menu)
end

describe 'GET index' do
it 'assigns all menus as @menus' do
  get restaurant_menus_path(@restaurant)
  assigns(:menus).should eq([menu])
end
end

describe 'GET all restaurants menus' do
it 'responds with 200' do
  get :index, { :id => @restaurant  }
  expect(response).to be_success
  expect(response.status).to eq(200)
  end
end
```

but the error is:

```
  1) MenusController GET index assigns all menus as @menus
 Failure/Error: get restaurant_menus_path(@restaurant)
 ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
   No route matches {:controller=>"menus", :action=>"/en/restaurants/52a20e4c6561721131010000/menus"}
 # ./spec/controllers/menus_controller_spec.rb:30:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

 2) MenusController GET all restaurants menus responds with 200
 Failure/Error: get :index, { :id => @restaurant  }
 ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
   No route matches {:action=>"index", :id=>"52a20e4c6561721131060000", :controller=>"menus"}
 # ./spec/controllers/menus_controller_spec.rb:37:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

here are the routes:

```
restaurant_menus_path    GET     (/:locale)/restaurants/:restaurant_id/menus(.:format)   menus#index
POST     (/:locale)/restaurants/:restaurant_id/menus(.:format)   menus#create
new_restaurant_menu_path     GET     (/:locale)/restaurants/:restaurant_id/menus/new(.:format)   menus#new
edit_restaurant_menu_path    GET     (/:locale)/restaurants/:restaurant_id/menus/:id/edit(.:format)  menus#edit
restaurant_menu_path     GET     (/:locale)/restaurants/:restaurant_id/menus/:id(.:format)   menus#show
PATCH    (/:locale)/restaurants/:restaurant_id/menus/:id(.:format)   menus#update
PUT  (/:locale)/restaurants/:restaurant_id/menus/:id(.:format)   menus#update
DELETE   (/:locale)/restaurants/:restaurant_id/menus/:id(.:format)   menus#destroy
```

interestingly is, that this test in menu_spec.rb is working..

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe 'Menu' do
  before :each do
    @restaurant = FactoryGirl.create(:random_restaurant)
    @menu = FactoryGirl.create(:menu)
  end

  describe 'GET /menus' do
    it 'responds with 200' do
      get restaurant_menu_path(@restaurant, @menu)
      expect(response).to be_success
      expect(response.status).to eq(200)
    end
  end

  describe 'GET all restaurants menus' do
    it 'responds with 200' do
      get restaurant_menus_path(@restaurant)
      expect(response).to be_success
      expect(response.status).to eq(200)
    end
  end
end
```

i really dont know why this test is not working.. :(

please.. i need some explanation.. if anyone can help.. please :)
resources to read are also welcome :)

thank you very much..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ok, i got it, the tests should look like this:

```
 it 'renders the index template' do
  get :index, { :restaurant_id => @restaurant  }
  expect(response).to render_template('index')
end
```

i had to add :restaurant_id.. then it worked.

Comment: Any chance you could point the controllers? I'm running into a similar issue, but I'm getting `#<Mongoid::Criteria`. Dunno why!. Also, how is that on your `before` block you create two different instances, where do you state that both are associated?

Comment: Sorry was on vacation.. i decalred it in the models. 

the menu model has something like this:
accepts_nested_attributes_for :restaurant

and my restaurant model this:
accepts_nested_attributes_for :menus

Comment: Thanks. I solved it. I don't remember what was the problem, but I believe it has to do something with the associations that **must** exist on the "child" resource (in the factory), or they will be treated as "unassociated" resources.

Answer (score 1):

In test `type:controller`when I do `get restaurant_menus_path(@restaurant)` that throws this error:

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
   No route matches {:action=>"/restaurant/1/menus", :controller=>"restaurants"}
```

In test type controller in the method get the first argument isn't the action in the controller:

So it works with:

```
get :index, { :restaurant_id => @restaurant  }
```